# JSON does not work... Process finished with exit code 0

Tags: python, json, pycharm, exit

i have installed json and have checked the 'project interpreter' in the 'settings' but it still doesn't work.

Any help would be great, thanks.

code:

```
 import json
import os

if os.path.isfile("./ages.json") and os.stat("./ages.json").st_size != 0: 
    old_file = open("./ages.json", "r+")  
    data = json.loads(old_file())  
    print("Current age is", data["age"], "-- adding a year")
    print("New age is", data["age"])
else:  # if no file then
    old_file = open("./ages.json", "w+")
    data = {"name": "Nickg", "age": 839}
    print("No file ffound, default age will be set to", data["age"])

old_file.seek(0) 
old_file.write(json.dumps(data))
```

i have tried importing just 'json' and simple json

This is the result:

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work" specifically? Exit code 0 means it did work. Did you check to see if the files had been modified?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so at your first line you have import json with one space before (I think you just did mistake in your question, not code)

Also, it would be nice if you add traceback to your quesiton, because exit code 0 means only that you have got an error

But what I think is problem in current code, is that fact you use `json.loads(old_file())`. Maybe try

```
with open('./ages.json', 'r+') as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())
```

Same with write mode

```
with open('./ages.json', 'w+') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(data))
```

Also, don't forget to close your file after all the operations
`f.close()`

You can use OOP:

```
class JSONFile:
    def __init__(self, filename: str):
        self.filename = filename
        if not filename.endswith('.json'):
            self.filename += '.json'
    def write(self, content):
        with open(self.filename, 'w') as f:
            f.write(str(json.dumps(content)))
            f.close()
    def read(self):
        with open(self.filename, 'r') as f:
            a = f.read()
            f.close()
        return json.loads(a)
    def append(self, content):
        with open(self.filename, 'a') as f:
            f.write(str(json.dumps(content)))
            f.close()
```

It works fine, I checked

Sorry, if didn't help I'm pretty new to programming and I can be incorrect

Comment: `data = json.loads(f.read())` should just be `data = json.load(f)`. Nice spot on the spurious function call, though

Comment: Thanks, I did a small edit with OOP example. Now author of this question might get answer

Comment: Thanks for the answers, i shortly found out the problem. I had been installing many packages from the project interpreter and after creating a new project my original code worked. I'm new to programming